# touch equivalent of focus() method?

Tags: javascript, iphone, blackberry, touch

You can pass focus to an element in javascript as such:

```
element.focus()
```

I'm doing that with a input text box and it works fine. The input box gets focus and the cursor is in it.

We now want to also trigger the soft keyboard on touch devices. By default, putting focus on a field via JS will move the cursor into the field, but won't open the keyboard until the user physically taps on the field.

Is there a way to trigger a touch event (I'm guessing touchstart) akin to this:

```
element.touchstart()
```

That doesn't work, but hoping there is some method for this...

BTW, this is primarily for webkit. We're trying to get this working on an iPhone and BB Torch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is `ontouchstart` instead of `touchstart`

Comment: ontouchstart would be the event listener, wouldn't it? If I put an ontouchstart listener on the text field it, indeed, does trigger if I call it via event.ontouchstart(). Alas, it does not launch the keyboard. Perhaps that's simply not doable from within the browser?